# ...hide the evidence before you know what hit/hits you

Tags: word-choice

> Even if you hide the marmalade in the remotest corner of the house, you can be sure that Carlotta will nose it out, devour it, and hide the evidence before you know what **hit/hits** you.

[Probable Source](http://freelancertestbd.blogspot.com/2015/04/odesk-uk-english-grammar-test-answer.html): Betty S. Azar and Stacy A. Hagen, *Understanding and Using English Grammar*

Which word in bold should I use? And could you please explain to me why you would use that verb?

Thanks.

Comment: *Never take any medication [before you know what **ails** you.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22before+you+know+what+ails+you%22)

Comment: Always take your medication with marmalade.  Unless Carlotta is around.

Comment: "Before you know what hit you is an idiom."  Even if "hit" were not technically correct, the idiom would still prevail.  But "hit" is correct.  Imagine you're just standing there and suddenly get bopped on the head.  A person near by might ask "Do you know what hit you?"

Comment: @FumbleFingers some people say [before "you know what hits you"](https://www.google.it/search?q=before+you+know+what+hit%2Fhits&oq=before+you+know+what+hit%2Fhits&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l2j69i61&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#tbm=bks&q=before+%22you+know+what+hits+you%22) Although the vast majority say ....["before you know what hit you"](https://www.google.it/search?q=before+you+know+what+hit%2Fhits&oq=before+you+know+what+hit%2Fhits&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l2j69i61&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#tbm=bks&q=before+%22you+know+what+hit+you%22).....

Comment: @Mari-Lou: I'm surprised there are so many written instances of something that sounds so "unusual" to my ear. It's still only 68, as against 1630 for the standard ***hit*** version (plus there are another 598 for the equally "normal-to-me" [*before you know **what's** hit you*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22before+you+know+what%27s+hit+you%22)). But it certainly doesn't look as if I could get away with claiming all those 68 instances are from nns or otherwise "incompetent" speakers. Perhaps there's more to this Q than meets the eye (I can't "parse" *before he knows what hits him*)

Answer (score 1):

Hit.

...before you know what hit you.
We have to know what hit us I.e already done I.e past tense.